# Windows Server 2008 R2 with Directory Browsing enabled displays a blank page

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, iis-7.5

I have installed Directory Browsing on my 2008 R2 server and enabled Directory Browsing on a particular directory, however even after enabling directory browsing it continues to show a blank page rather than the contents of the directory.  I enabled Failed Request Tracing the logs shows no errors and returns a 200 status code.  Any help or direction would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this?  Having the same issues...

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you don't have a blank `index.html` or `default.aspx` in the directory root? That would explain why there are no errors, as you server would be serving up the blank pages successfully.

It's not a failed Directory Browsing request, that would throw a 403 Forbidden.

Comment: I actually have default document disabled on the directory and I doubled checked and the only thing in this directory is PDF documents.